# Adding, Updating, and Storing Outputs of Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On a Facebook page, it tracks the admin who posted each post. With that, I wanted to get and use the Facebook Graph API to get the posts, the admin who posted each post, and the amount of likes on each post. This makes an easy way to see how each admin is doing and how their posts are overall performing.

I've been able to achieve getting the outputs using
`/me/posts?fields=admin_creator,likes.limit(0).summary(true)&limit=30,fields`

This is able to output the following:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "admin_creator": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "id": "432423543"
      },
      "id": "435345345_543534534",
      "likes": {
        "data": [
        ],
        "summary": {
          "total_count": 710,
          "can_like": true,
          "has_liked": false
        }
      }
    },
```

...and so on for 30 posts (values changed above for privacy reasons).

I'm looking to possible use PHP to add up the values and display as a list or chart. With multiple admins, I'm looking for it to take the total_count values and add it to the respective admin. Then also count the amount of posts counted and put up an average likes/post.

I'm fairly new to PHP but I imagine that this could with done with a loop to check all of the posts and add the total_count to the respective admin variable and also add a post to the total number of posts per admin each time through the loop.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could come up with a solution. I'm fairly new to PHP but am willing to learn. This would make managing the staff on my Facebook page much easier and I'm sure it can benefit many other pages as well.

Example Output:

```
John Doe: 5049 likes in 4 posts (1262.25 avg)
Melissa Snow: 1289 likes in 2 posts (644.5 avg)
Pringles Man: 2589 in 5 posts (517.8 avg)
Admin Four: 235 likes in 1 post (235 avg)
```

Being completely new to PHP and Facebook's PHP SDK, here is my current code:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
        'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
    ]);
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    $response = $fb->get('/me/posts?fields=admin_creator,likes.limit(0).summary(true)&limit=30');
    $graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
    /* handle the result */
?>
```

The current code does not give me any errors but I have no idea what to do from here to get the `name` of `admin_creator` and the `total_count` of `summary` of `likes`.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for getting people to write your code. It is for helping you to code. Try and then ask if it doesn't work

Comment: @WizKid I am aware of that and that's why I said that I'm willing to learn in the original post. I have done a lot of research into this but still seem to be stuck on what to do. I'm currently unable to even get past the part of including the Facebook PHP SDK without it throwing an error. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Then show your code and what error you get.

Comment: @WizKid added code and error to original post. I've seen people have the same problem but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: FacebookRequest doesn't have a method called execute. So you can't call that. Where did you get the code from?

Comment: @WizKid That's what other sources have told me but if you go to the graph explorer and press the "Get Code" button at the bottom next to "Save Session", then go to the PHP SDK tab, it uses execute.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Facebook SDK?

Comment: @WizKid Yeah I believe so. If execute is no longer a function then is there a work around or replacement code? This is the exact code the Graph API gave me.

Comment: @WizKid I found a fix to my current error and have updated the code in the original post. I would appreciate some guidance on where to go from here to achieve what I'm looking for because I am completely lost.